# dispatch_queue_t need to be released using dispatch_release()?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have two `GCD` blocks that are async. The first is for the background thread, the second runs on the main thread.  This works great, but I just saw somewhere talking that I might need to release them using `dispatch_release()`.  E.g.:

```
// Use gcd
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.awesome", 0);
dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();

//  do the long running work in bg async queue
// within that, call to update UI on main thread.
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 
   // Do work in the background



    // Release
    dispatch_release(queue);

   dispatch_async(main, ^{ 

       // Main


       // Release
       dispatch_release(main);

   });//end
});//end
```

Is this true?  Do I need to release them here?

Comment: Per the comments in the header file you need to invoke dispatch_release() on any queue that you create.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only release queues that you create; don't release the main queue or the global concurrent queues (or, again, any you did not create yourself).  It's also not a good idea to nest the release within the work block enqueued on that queue, as you're doing, because that's doing it in the wrong scope and this:

```
queue = dispatch_queue_create(...)
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ something; dispatch_release(queue); });
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ something else}); // CRASH!
```

Won't work when you later change the code to add that 2nd `dispatch_async()`.  Always pairing your create/release calls in the same scope, assuming that you can, is a better stylistic choice.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to release it outside of the dispatch_asynch call?

Comment: Yes.  Specifically, you need to do it in the same scope as the create call lest you set a land-mine for yourself that you later step on, as I illustrated in my answer (the only exception to this rule might be finalizers, but let's not confuse things :) )

Answer (score 13):

You only need to release the queue created with `dispatch_queue_create`. The main queue will always exist, and it doesn't make sense to release it.

Any blocks added to the queue will retain the queue itself, so you can safely call `dispatch_release(queue)` after your `dispatch_async` call. Best to do this outside the block after the code you've written here.

Comment: Ok, but if I do it outside the queue, won't it get released automatically?

Comment: @NicHubbard It will get released when all the queue's work is done, for instance you could create a queue, dispatch 3 - 4 blocks to it, and release it after the dispatch calls. The queue will remain retained until all the blocks have finished their corresponding tasks. At this point you no longer need this queue.